# Binary serialization between .NET Core and .NET

Tags: c#, .net-core

So i have dictionary of key and value where value is an object, when exchanging the binary data between .NET Core and .NET and vice versa the serialization fails with

`` System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Unable to load type System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[[SharedLib.HostPropertyType, DataInterfaces, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] required for deserialization.' ``

which makes perfect sense since target type is located in another library, the question is whether there is a way to avoid this without creating custom types ?

Thanks.

Comment: The binary serialized object can be different in different versions of the Net Library.  So serialize will not work unless the version of Net is the same.  Yo can use structure and then use marshall class to convert the structure to bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although it's something you haven't specified, it looks like you're using the `BinaryFormatter`. This is a awkward formatter to use, becasue it can be very picky about what assemblies the types it uses comes from, which it looks like you've run in to.

However, you *should* be able to [specify how the formatter binds its types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter.binder?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netcore-3.1#System_Runtime_Serialization_Formatters_Binary_BinaryFormatter_Binder) by setting the `Binder` property.

If you check out the MS Docs link above, you should be able to see what you need to do. I've copied it here too:

```
sealed class Version1ToVersion2DeserializationBinder : SerializationBinder
{
    public override Type BindToType(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        Type typeToDeserialize = null;

        // For each assemblyName/typeName that you want to deserialize to
        // a different type, set typeToDeserialize to the desired type.
        String assemVer1 = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName;
        String typeVer1 = "Version1Type";

        if (assemblyName == assemVer1 && typeName == typeVer1)
        {
            // To use a type from a different assembly version,
            // change the version number.
            // To do this, uncomment the following line of code.
            // assemblyName = assemblyName.Replace("1.0.0.0", "2.0.0.0");

            // To use a different type from the same assembly,
            // change the type name.
            typeName = "Version2Type";
        }

        // The following line of code returns the type.
        typeToDeserialize = Type.GetType(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
            typeName, assemblyName));

        return typeToDeserialize;
    }
}
```

The general idea that you want to do I think is essentially tell the formatter that it's OK to use the .net core version of the IDictionary, by swapping the assembly that it's looking for with the one you're using.

As you haven't specified exactly what versions of .net core and fraemwork you're using, I can't really be any more specific, but that should help you out.